# Is there any way to pull the build version of the code we have commited on SVN

Tags: java, android, svn

Is there any way to pull the build version of the code I have committed on Subversion? I am using Subversion on Eclipse. I am in sync with the repository. Now I want to show the build details of the code I have committed so that it can be shown on an Android device screen. Is there any way to do so? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Maven, Ant or Gradle to build your Android project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this: using [this Gradle plugin](https://github.com/noamt/gradle-build-number-plugin) you can have Gradle put SCM type and revision to standard-out and build manifest.